# Laptop shuts off when stacking on identical laptop

Tags: laptop, shutdown

I am a high school student, and all students are issued Acer TravelMate P249 Laptops.  If my laptop is open, and I pick it up and put it on top of another identical laptop, it just hibernates.  In Middle school, we were issued Acer Chromebooks, and they did the same thing.  Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wild guess, magnets in the lid tell it when it's closed.

Placing another identical machine in line above will likely trigger the sensors in the same way.

Potential fix is stack each one the other way round, 180° horizontally, or just don't stack them.

Comment: I just wanted to answer the same. or set "do nothing" when the lid is closed:)

Comment: If it has a 'do nothing' option; but that's going to lead long-term to lots of flat batteries ;)

Comment: I never even thought of that, wow.  I will try that at school today.  Thanks!

Comment: 180° may not work, it depends how sensitive they are.

Comment: the do nothing will also still turn off the screen. (and can confirm. Freaked out when I thought my laptop was dead. Picked it up and it magically started working. Took me a few times to realize...)

Comment: should be easy to test - just put a magnet near the lid and/or front of the PC and see what happens.